# How to ignore a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when deleting an entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an app that reads a lot of data into memory and processes it in a batches.

What I want is for entity framework to ignore `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` when deleting an entity that has already been deleted.

The reason is that by the time an entity has been processed and marked for deletion, it may already have been deleted from the DB.

Obliviously deleting a row that has already been deleted isn't a problem and shouldn't cause an error, I just need a way to tell entity framework that :)

Example

```
Db.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
Db.SaveChanges();
```

Causes an error if `itemToRemove` has already been deleted.

Note: `Db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;` doesn't fix this as another thread suggested.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about?

```
Db.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;

bool saveFailed;
do
{
    saveFailed = false;
    try
    {
       Db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
       saveFailed = true;
       var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
       //The MSDN examples use Single so I think there will be only one
       //but if you prefer - do it for all entries
       //foreach(var entry in ex.Entries)
       //{
       if(entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
          //When EF deletes an item its state is set to Detached
          //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx
          entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
       else
          entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues());
          //throw; //You may prefer not to resolve when updating
       //}
    }
} while (saveFailed);
```

More here:
[Resolving optimistic concurrency exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592904)

Comment: looks interesting. what happens if if there are many items to be removed at the time savechanges is called. I will need to detach the ones that have been previously deleted and then continue saving/deleting the others.

Comment: SaveChanges is done in a transaction so nothing is actually deleted until the last item causing a concurrency problem is fixed

Comment: Ah ha i see. 
In that case could i not do this...
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            ex.Entries.Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
            Db.SaveChanges();
    }

Comment: Given that the examples on MSDN call `ex.Entries.Single` then I assume that `ex.Entries` will only ever contain one record so your code would do the same thing...but maybe you're not happy with that assumption...What I'm not getting is why you think the transaction rollback prevents you writing it that way?

Comment: well according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception.entries(v=vs.103).aspx `ex.Entries` contains all the entities that could not be saved.
The only problem i have with the while loop is that it will spin forever if there is an entity that could not be saved for a reason other than `entry.State == EntityState.Deleted`.

Comment: thanks for your answer though, it has definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, so the base class `DbUpdateException` allows for many entries. I think it is likely that `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` will only ever contain one -  and code edited to prevent the infinite loop

Answer (score 5):

I posted this question a long time ago but it has recently had some attention so I though I would add the solution I actually use.

```
//retry up to 5 times
for (var retries = 0; retries < 5; retries++)
{
    try
    {
        Db.SaveChanges();
        break;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        foreach (var entity in ex.Entries)
        {
            entity.State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
    }
}
```

Things I considered - I did NOT want to use `ReloadAsync()` or `ObjectContext.Refresh` as I wanted to ignore items deleted in another process WITHOUT any additional database overhead.
I added in the for loop as a simple protection against infinite loops - not something that should be able to happen, but I'm a belt and braces approach man and not a fan of `while(true)` if it can be avoided.
No need to a local variable like `isDone` or `saveFailed` - simply break if we saved successfully.
No need to cast `ex.Entries` to a list in order to enumerate it - just because you can write something on one line doesn't make it better.

Answer (score 3):

You could handle the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and then call `Refresh(RefreshMode,IEnumerable)` with RefreshMode.StoreWins and your deleted entities as parameter.

```
try{
  Db.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
  Db.SaveChanges();
}
catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
  IObjectContextAdapter adapter = Db;

  adapter.ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Deleted));
  Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I have had a look at `refresh` but as this will be running in very large batches in a multi threaded environment, i don't want to take the aditional hit/cost of reading the data a second time from the db.

Comment: what i really need is for savechanges to ignore any `DbUpdateConcurrencyException ` errors and complete the transaction without having to re-read entities from the db.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592904 but where I added an infite loop counter (just in case, you never know, right?) and looping through all the entries in the exception's list.

```
var maxTriesCounter = 20;
bool saveFailed;
do
{
    saveFailed = false;
    maxTriesCounter--;
    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        saveFailed = true;
        foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
        {
            entry.Reload();
        }
    }
} while (saveFailed && maxTriesCounter > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use.  Detach all problem records after the save.

```
Db.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;

while(true)
    try {
        Db.SaveChanges();
        break;
    } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) {
        ex.Entries.ToList().ForEach(x=>x.State=EntityState.Detached);
    }
```

Or you could add a custom SaveChanges function to your DbContext class and use it instead whenever you need to ignore those errors.

```
    public int SaveChanges_IgnoreConcurrencyExceptions  () {
        while(true)
            try {
                return this.SaveChanges();
            } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) {
                ex.Entries.ToList().ForEach(x => x.State=EntityState.Detached);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't that exactly what I put in my comment on the accepted answer?

Comment: It's close.  The loop structure is different, and I'm detaching every failed entry instead of limiting it to deleted entries (which could have caused infinite loops).  Also I'm suggesting making a new `SaveChanges` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
    public async Task DeleteItem(int id)
    {
        bool isDone = false;
        while (!isDone)
        {
            var item= await dbContext.Items.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.id== id);
            if (item== null)
                return;

            dbContext.Items.Delete(item);
            try
            {
                await dbContext.CommitAsync();
                return;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach:

```
        context.Delete(item);
        bool saveFailed;
        do
        {
            saveFailed = false;

            try
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                saveFailed = true;
                var entity = ex.Entries.Single();
                await entity.Single().ReloadAsync();

                if (entity.State == EntityState.Unchanged)// entity is already updated
                    context.Delete(item);;
                else if (entity.State == EntityState.Detached) // entity is already deleted
                    saveFailed =false;
            }
        } while (saveFailed);
```

`ReloadAsync()` method as of [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.reloadasync?view=efcore-5.0) :

> Reloads the entity from the database overwriting any property values
> with values from the database.
>
> The entity will be in the Unchanged state after calling this method,
> unless the entity does not exist in the database, in which case the
> entity will be Detached. Finally, calling Reload on an Added entity
> that does not exist in the database is a no-op. Note, however, that an
> Added entity may not yet have had its permanent key value created.

Comment: `var entity = ex.Entries.Single();` will throw an exception if more than one entry has been modified.  See- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception.entries?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads

Comment: @herostwist ,In situation where we are deleting a `Principal` entity it may be true, but if our entity is `Dependent`  just relying  on `Single()` method would suffice.