# Entity Framework delete without select and Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to delete a record if it exists using Entity Framework - I want to generate something like

```
delete from tbl where id = 1
```

I don't care whether any records exist, I just want to delete them if they do.  I should be able to do with without selecting them first like this:

```
var record = new tbl { id = 1, rel = new tbl_related { tbl_id = 1 } };
context.tbl.Attach(tbl);
context.tbl.Remove(tbl);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The syntax might not exactly be there because this isn't a copy and paste, and I've added the foreign key relationship to show that I'm taking this into account.

On running this code the correct SQL is generated by EF and run but I get a System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException saying "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded".

However, I'm fully expecting zero rows to be deleted a lot of the time.  Any ideas on how I can get around this?

I've been pointed to [How to ignore a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when deleting an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295232/how-to-ignore-a-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-when-deleting-an-entity) as a possible duplicate.  This suggests handling the DbUpdateConcurrencyException which I am now doing (and ignoring), but that post talks about trying to delete rows that might have been deleted - I want to delete rows that might never have existed.  I know this might just be a question of semantics because the resolution is the same but I want to highlight that I am doing something that I see as perfectly reasonable and the Framework is not handling it very well.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when deleting an entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295232/how-to-ignore-a-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-when-deleting-an-entity)

Comment: Thanks @Colin.  I'll accept your comment because the resolution might the same, but the scenario in that post is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [extension for EF on github](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus) that allows you to update and delete entities with a single call to the database.

With this extension you can do something like this:

```
context.tbl.Delete(t => t.Id == 1);
```

A single call should eliminate your DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

Comment: We use it in our projects too! Works like a charm.

Comment: doesn't support `context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: @Toolkit If you want to apply your deletes together with other changes, you can wrap everything inside a transaction.